# EJS ReferenceError: success_msg is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm currently working on a library site for my school with login and administration features.
I'm new to node.js and EJS in general and i recently reworked pretty much everything regarding routing and page serving to use EJS and express.
To implement user feedback i want to use flash messages.

This is the detailed error:

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\views\index.ejs:15
    13|   </div>
    14| </nav>
 >> 15| <%- include ("./partials/messages.ejs") %>
    16| <div class="rect" id="rect">
    17|   <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
    18|   <h1>Willkommen</h1>

C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\views\partials\messages.ejs:1
 >> 1| <% if(typeof errors != 'undefined'){ %> <% errors.forEach(function(error) { %>
    2|     <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    3|       <%= error.msg %>
    4|       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">

success_msg is not defined
    at eval (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\views\partials\messages.ejs:22:8)
    at messages (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:691:17)
    at include (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:689:39)
    at eval (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\views\index.ejs:12:17)
    at index (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:691:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\express-ejs-layouts\lib\express-layouts.js:77:18)
    at C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\routes\index.js:6:35
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Juli\Documents\Git\gt-db\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
```

And this is the code:

````
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <%= error.msg %>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <% }); %> <% } %> <% if(success_msg != ''){ %>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <%= success_msg %>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <% } %> <% if(error_msg != ''){ %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <%= error_msg %>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <% } %> <% if(error != ''){ %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <%= error %>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <% } %>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to change:

```
if(success_msg != '')
```

to

```
if (typeof success_msg !== 'undefined' && success_msg !== '')
```

As you can see below, you can use `typeof` even when the variable doesn't exist, but trying to use it then throws an error:

```js
if (typeof success_msg !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('it exists');
}

console.log('typeof works');

if (success_msg !== '') {
    console.log('it exists');
}

console.log('equality check doesnt');
```